# Newly installed DIR-615 - how to connect to the wireless?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I've just installed a D-Link DIR 615, but can't figure out how to connect to the wireless..

When I double click my wireless icon in the tray, it does show the new network.

Its starts the "WiFi protected setup wizard" and the first thing it asks for is the "Device Ownership Password".  I have no idea what that is - I've tried the PIN and the router password.

On the next page it says:

```
SSID: _(name)__
Security type: _wpa2 personal aes ccmp_
Password: _some long key that is not what I entered during router setup_
```

I change the key to the one I created when setting up the router.  I've also tried leaving the key as it is shown in the dialog. But it does not connect either way. All it says is "Configuration failed"

So how do I connect to the new wireless network??

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell us which operating system you are using? It could be an OS problem, so knowing the one you are using will help a lot.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess Windows XP... I mean look at those title bars!

Answer (score 1):

If my sources are right, first step is to connect to the router using a wired connection.

After that you need to go to it's control panel at http://192.168.0.1, if you haven't changed it, and then go to setup tab.

There click on the wireless setup wizard. First step is to set a new SSID. Pick some name which will mean something to you and will be easy to remember.

After that set up the encryption method. There's no reason why not to chose WPA2 (it seems that your computer supports it), so pick it.

After that, you'll get to the wireless setup password page. You'll need a password which is between 8 and 63 characters in length. Pick one which will be easy to remember, but not too simple. You can use letters and numbers (the manual only shows numbers, so that needs to be clarified), so please do so. Please note that term used to refer to the "password" in this case is pre-shared key, so expect to see that on your operating system.

After all that click save and go to the computer which needs to connect. Find the network with the name you set and use the pre-shared key you set in the wizard to connect.

Do keep in mind that the password used to access settings page of the router and one used for WiFI do not need to be same and it's a good idea to keep them different.

Comment: I did all that.. connect with cable - check. Control panel at .0.1 - check. Set SSID - check. Encryption WPA2 - check.  Choose a long password - check. Found the network in the wireless networks list - check. Tried to connect - check.  It asked for the ""Device Ownership Password", not the long password created earlier...

Comment: @JK123 Which operating system are you using? Can you provide a screen-shot of the problematic window?

Comment: And a Google search shows that "Device Ownership Password" probably means the PIN number on the bottom of the router.  I tried that but got the 2nd dialog shown above, and cannot get past that one.

Comment: @Andreja - edited the post with a screenshot. Running Windows XP

Comment: What happens if you try connecting with the normal Windows Wireless config?

Comment: @nhinkle What do you mean "normal Windows Wireless config"... I double clicked on the wireless icon, the one that shows the list of available networks.. this is the "normal" way afaik.

Comment: The windows you have shown above are not the built-in Windows Wireless Configuration utility. You can get instructions from Microsoft's website here: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/setup/winxp/network.mspx#2

Answer (score 0):

Pre request :(for your DIR615)

- Minimum system requirement Xp SP3
- You have to use the Ethernet port on your modem for the first time

Configuring :

- Run DIR615.exe, click install router
- write down the login password on the provided CD holder.

Open Browser :(Important)

- Type **192.168.0.1**
- Select Admin from the drop-down menu and leave the password blank by default.

Setup :

- You may click Setup Wizard
  There will be lot of options available to setup your account depends on your ISP . 
  Choose **PPPoE** if your ISP uses it,
  (You Have to mention your Connection type ,which your ISP uses in your question.)
  For example if you use PPPoE (for most BSNl home users) enter details as follows,

For PPPoE:

Select PPPoE (Username/Password) from the drop-down menu in Internet connection type panel.

**Address Mode:** Select Static if your ISP assigned you the IP address, subnet mask,
gateway, and DNS server addresses. In most cases, select Dynamic.

**Username & Password :** Enter your PPPoE username ,then enter  PPPoE password and then retype the password in the next
box.
(ISP service name is optional)

**MAC Address:** The default MAC Address is set to the Internet port’s physical interface
MAC address on the Broadband Router. It is not recommended that you
change the default MAC address unless required by your ISP.

Leave blank for primary and secondary DNS address if you not uses Static IP

**Maximum Idle Time:** Enter a maximum idle time during which the Internet connection is maintained during inactivity. To disable this feature,
enable Auto-reconnect.

**MTU:** Maximum Transmission Unit - you may need to change the MTU for optimal performance with your specific ISP. 1492 is
the default MTU.

**Connect Mode:** Select either Always-on, On-Demand, or Manual.

If you have any doubts feel free to ask here by giving additional details .For more details just visit their website and download product manual ,that's it you rocks.